# Scriptlet variable doesn't get evaluated inside an attribute of a custom JSP tag

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, syntax, jsp-tags

I am trying to have a JavaScript function called when I click a link. This JavaScript function is definied in an attribute of a JSP tag and I am trying to pass a *scriptlet* variable to the function. However, it doesn't get evaluated. The relevant part of the code is:

```xml
<span>
  <mysecurity:secure_link id='<%="editButton_"+commentUUID%>' entitlement="" 
    actionOnClick="editComment('<%= commentUUID %>');return false;"
    isSurroundedByBrackets="true" enableTitle="" disableLink="<%=disableLink%>">
    <span style="color:#0033BB; font:8pt arial;">
      <bean:message key="button.edit" />
    </span>
   </mysecurity:secure_link>
</span>
```

IE8 mentions a JavaScript error in the bottom left corner. When I right click and view source, the generated HTML is:

```
onclick="editComment('<%= commentUUID %>');return false;"
```

So, the `<%=commentUUID%>` is not been evaluated in the `actionOnClick` attribute, but it's successfully been evaluated in `id` attribute.

How is this caused and how can I fix it?

Comment: `javascript:` does not belong into an `onclick` attribute.

Comment: What happens when you click the link? Is there an error message displayed in either the Firebug or WebKit developer tools' console? Or does nothing happen?

Comment: It was a comment. Not an answer to your question. Without seeing the generated HTML code it's hard to say what's broken - but `javascript:` inside `onclick="..."` is always unnecessary.

Comment: @matt: just plain raw javascript. `onclick="editComment(...)"`. The only time you'd use a javascript: pseudourl is in `<a href="javascript:...">...</a>`.

Comment: It says error on page in the bottom left corner (I am using IE8) then when I right click and view source, the relevant line is:

    onclick="editComment('<%= commentUUID %>');return false;"

'<%= commentUUID %>' is normally replaced by its string value defined in the jsp normally but it is not

Comment: In other words, the *scriptlet* did not get evaluated? Is this line of code really inside a JSP file? (that's namely the only language who understands and parses those old fashioned *scriptlets*).

Comment: How are you generating your html? It looks like your server code is interpreting the commentUUID variable as part of the string

Comment: @BalusC  yes it is its defined a few lines above in the jsp file

Comment: Are other *scriptlets* inside the JSP file evaluated? There's namely a (global) configuration option available which disables *scriptlets* altogether because that's a since 2003 discouraged way of controlling the flow and accessing variables in JSP. For that rather taglibs/EL should have been used instead.

Comment: What happens when you click the link? Is there an error message displayed in either the Firebug or WebKit developer tools' console? Or does nothing happen?

@BalusC: Sorry for saving my comment as an answer. It was inadvertent.

Comment: @scrappedcola all of my html is generated in different JSPs

Comment: @BalusC the scriplets are behaving correctly everywhere else in the jsp, just not in this case. I assume its because its making a link to the javascript function or something

Comment: Well, if it doesn't work, then it's not physically part of a JSP file. Perhaps it's actually in a `.js` (JavaScript) file? Or perhaps it's actually in a JSP taglib like `<x:xyz actionOnclick="...">` and you omitted that detail for brevity?

Comment: @waveslider nothing happens and when i click view source it shows this onclick="editComment('<%= commentUUID %>');return false;" meaning that the scriplet was not evaluated correctly

Comment: @BalusC on the same line in the jsp I have id='<%="editButton_"+commentUUID%>' and that scriplet does get read.  Is it because they are on the same line?

Comment: @BalusC I should have pasted the full line. It is

<span><mysecurity:secure_link id='<%="editButton_"+commentUUID%>' entitlement="" actionOnClick="editComment('<%= commentUUID %>');return false;" isSurroundedByBrackets="true" enableTitle="" disableLink="<%=disableLink%>" ><span style="color:#0033BB; font:8pt arial; "><bean:message key="button.edit" /></span></mysecurity:secure_link></span>

Comment: I clarified the question based on the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What finally worked for me, with the @BalusC 's advice was to use editcomment(this.id.split('_')[1]).  The correct working code is as follows:

```
<span>
  <mysecurity:secure_link id='<%="editButton_"+commentUUID%>' entitlement="" 
      actionOnClick="javascript:editComment(this.id.split('_')[1]);return false;"
      isSurroundedByBrackets="true" enableTitle="" disableLink="<%=disableLink%>">
      <span style="color:#0033BB; font:8pt arial;">
         <bean:message key="button.edit" />
      </span>
  </mysecurity:secure_link>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether the `<mysecurity:secure_link>` is a custom or an existing 3rd party JSP tag library. Modern JSP tags usually do not evaluate legacy *scriptlet* expressions. You should rather be using [EL (Expression Language)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) instead.

First ensure that `commentUUID` variable is been stored as an attribute of the page or request scope so that it's available to EL, like as the following example in a preprocessing [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info):

```
request.setAttribute("commentUUID", commentUUID);
```

*or* using another *scriptlet* in JSP:

```
<% request.setAttribute("commentUUID", commentUUID); %>
```

*or* using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)'s `<c:set>` in JSP:

```xml
<c:set var="commentUUID"><%=commentUUID%></c:set>
```

then you can access it as follows in EL:

```xml
<mysecurity:secure_link actionOnClick="editComment('${commentUUID}');return false;" />
```

Comment: Bringing the entire app up to date would take way to long sadly

Comment: This did not work, is there some kind of configuration I need to set to get EL to be understood?

Comment: Is this a custom or 3rd party tag? If custom, make sure that `<rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>` is been set in taglib attribute declaration. If 3rd party, workaround it by extracting it from the generated HTML element ID. E.g. `editcomment(this.id.split('_')[1])`.